# Changing the number of records to fetch in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot service which has a kafka consumer. I'm using `spring-kafka` for creating the consumer.

From the documentation, it says `max.poll.records` property will help in restricting the number of records to fetch.

But my problem is, I want to change the value of `max.poll.records` based on several other conditions.

How can we achieve this using `spring-kafka`? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean change it at runtime, it can't be done; the property is sent to Kafka when the consumer is created.

To change it, you would have to stop the container, change the property, and restart the container. You would need a custom consumer factory that subclasses `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` and overrides

```
protected KafkaConsumer<K, V> createKafkaConsumer(Map<String, Object> configs) {
```

to change the property at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the input. Yes, I want to get only `n` the number of messages from the topic. Stopping the container might take time considering the load we have

Comment: In that case, you would need to create consumers yourself and not use the listener container.

Comment: Thanks!! Do you mean, override `createKafkaConsumer` and update the `fetcher.maxPollRecords` dynamically?

Comment: No; I didn't; you can't change the `Fetcher`; the field is `final` (as is the `Fetcher` itself). You would need to create a new consumer for each different fetch size.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the input.

Comment: are you able to achieve this . if yes please share the code snippet